# Documentation on system fields in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, guidance

Although it looks as a trivial question, I cannot find any detailed documentation on all system fields defined in SharePoint Online. There are only available scarce and outdated tables with [field names and IDs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_yeager/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-sharepoint-internal-field-names/). Is anybody aware of one place public reference regarding every system field existing in SharePoint Online with detailed description of meaning and usage for the field available from a single source? Thank you.

Comment: Check if this article is useful to you: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-list

Comment: @imp.MSFT, Thank you very much. It is precisely the info I was looking for. Please send it as an answer. I must confess, this prominent article is quite poorly indexed in Google. No search I ve tried brought it into view.

Comment: OK. I have done. You can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article defines the internal data types used in the list infrastructure of a SharePoint website. You can refer to it:

[Field element (List)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-list)